# How to avoid dataseries to fall under legend in matplotlib plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any automatic way of manipulating legend in matplotlib to avoid overlapping data points and legend? I have lots of data points and fixed y axis range, can I instruct matplotlib move the legend to left or down if it's on datapoints. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1, 100)
y = -1/x

plt.plot(x,y, label='x and y', linewidth=30)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually position the legend to the position that you want it, the documentation can be found [here.](http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html). You can also move it off the plotting area of the graph to avoid any chance of an overlap as shown in the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1, 100)
y = -1/x

plt.plot(x,y, label='x and y', linewidth=30)

#adjust the plot to allow the legend to fit nicely
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,right = 0.75)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.5), loc=2)   # move the legend
plt.show()
```

The resulting image is shown below:

[image]

Note: If you plan on moving the legend outside of the plotting area then you may have to adjust your plots as I have done in the code above.

Comment: appreciate your answer, but my legend is too long (data points with lengthy description) so this would make the actual chart very narrow.

Comment: Ok, I suppose you have a few options then. Assuming you don't want to cut down the text in your legend, _1)_ you could reduce the fontsize of your legend. _2)_ if you know the rough shape of the plot beforehand then you could position your legend accordingly _3)_ increase the size of your figure window. I suppose the best thing to do would be a mixture of 1 and 3?